# How to disable pop-up error messages for code editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

How can I disable this new style of pop-up error messages in the "Visual Studio 2022" in code editor? Thank you.

[image: "Visual Studio 2022" code editor pop-up error message.]

Comment: Interesting that you had this option enabled by default, thought it'd be something you opt in to especially as it's an experimental feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Visual Studio, go to `Tools`->`Options...`->`Text Editor`->`C#`->`Advanced` and uncheck the `Display diagnostics inline (experimental)` option.

See attached screenshot:[image]

Comment: I have updated your answer with an English version of your screenshot, hope you don't mind. Interesting to see those options in a different language though. :)

Comment: You are Right! Well Done ! :)